How to incorporate Select All to select2 in DataTables
I have some code that creates a DataTables table and adds a dropdown to let users filter the options.
var datatable = $table.dataTable({
    initComplete: function() {
        function addDropDown(xthis, column_num){
            var column = xthis.api().column(column_num);
            var title = $(column.header()).html().replace(/[\W]/g, '-');
            var select = $('<br><select id="' + title + '" class="select2" ></select>')
                .appendTo($('#' + title + '2')) // .appendTo($(column.header()))
                .on('change', function() {
                    var data = $.map($(this).select2('data'), function(value, key) {
                        return value.text ? $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(value.text) : null;
                    });
                    if (data.length === 0) {
                        data = [""];
                    }
                    
                    //join array into string with regex or (|)
                    var val = data.join('|');

                    //search for the option(s) selected
                    column
                        .search(val ? val : '', true, false)
                        .draw();
                });
            // Set specific values to filter for in each column
            if(column_num == 1) {
                var value_list = ['Platform1', 'Platform2', 'Platform3']
            } else if(column_num == 2) {
                var value_list = ['Category1','Category2','Category3']
            } else if(column_num == 3) {
                var value_list = ["Worldwide","United States",'Canada']
            } else {
                return true;
            }
            for(var value in value_list){
                select.append('<option value="' + value_list[value] + '">' + value_list[value] + '</option>');
            }
            
            
            /*// Select All
            var $selectAll = $('<button type="button">Select All</button>');
            select.prepend($selectAll);

            $selectAll.on('click', function (e) {
              var $results = $rendered.find('.select2-results__option[aria-selected=false]');
              
              // Get all results that aren't selected
              $results.each(function () {
                var $result = $(this);
                
                // Get the data object for it
                var data = $result.data('data');
                
                // Trigger the select event
                self.trigger('select', {
                  data: data
                });
              });
              
              self.trigger('close');
            });
            
            //use column title as selector and placeholder
            $('#' + title).select2({
                multiple: true,
                closeOnSelect: false,
                placeholder: "Filter " + title,
                //width: '100%'
            });*/

            //initially clear select otherwise first option is selected
            $('.select2').val(null).trigger('change');
        }
        addDropDown(this, 1);
        addDropDown(this, 2);
        addDropDown(this, 3);
        $("#Platform").click(function(event){
            event.stopPropagation();
        })
        


    },
});

Here is how it looks on my website: 
How do I implement 'Select All/None' on the top of the dropdown option?
From the answer here I tried to add this code:
if(data[0] == '\\(Select All\\)'){
                            $('#' + title).select2('destroy').find('option').prop('selected', 'selected').end().select2();
                        }

But this returns an error of:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'current')

However manually running $('#' + title).select2('destroy').find('option').prop('selected', 'selected').end().select2(); works to select all and filter the data
